# Maintain locale after login in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

On a multilingual website using Symfony, I've got a page with a login form embedded in the sidebar. Let's say I'm on the spanish version, the current url is `mysite.com/es`. On this page, `$request->getLocale()` gives me `'es'`, everything is fine.

However, if I submit the login form on this page, I get to `mysite.com`. The `'es'` part in the url has disappeared and `$request->getLocale()` gives me `'en'`. How can I make it so that my url and my locale don't change?

My form:

```
<form id="login-form" method="POST" action="/login-check">
    <input type="text" id="userEmail" name="_username">
    <input type="password" id="userPassword" name="_password">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ fos_csrf_provider.generateCsrfToken('authenticate') }}">
</form>
```

My firewall:

```
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        login_path: / 
        check_path: /login_check
    logout:
        path: my_site_logout
        target: /
        success_handler: my_site.logout_success_handler
    anonymous:    true
    remember_me:
        key:        %secret%
```

Comment: Try to create a login listener then redirect to the right locate
http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the following:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

Sticky locale. I used this in one of my projects.